# How to put the QLPreviewPanel show as a popover in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, popover, quicklook

[image]

I would like to make a Popover that can show as a popover like the spotlight search implementation? I can only use traditional way to show a Quicklook window on the centre, but I would like to make something like this:

How can I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by creating a [QLPreviewView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Quartz/Reference/QLPreviewView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) instance embedded within a [NSPopover](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Then, create a NSObject subclass that conforms to the QLPreviewItem protocol and set the `previewItem` property on your `QLPreviewView` like when working with the traditional QuickLook `QLPreviewPanel`.

```
QLPreviewView *view = [[QLPreviewView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 800, 100) style:QLPreviewViewStyleNormal];

JPQuickLookItem *item = [[JPQuickLookItem alloc] init];
item.previewItemURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/josh/Desktop/Test.png"];
item.previewItemTitle = @"Test.png";
view.previewItem = item;
```

I've created a [sample Swift implementation here](https://github.com/josh-/QLPreviewView-NSPopover-example).

Comment: Where the hell did you get the JPQuickLookItem?

Comment: `JPQuickLookItem` is just a simple class that conforms to the [QLPreviewItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Quartz/Reference/QLPreviewItem_Protocol/index.html) protocol. I've published the implementation in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/josh-/874826146a0238f5c26aaea404b2b381).