# Swift Mac Quick Look get image displayed

Tags: swift, swift3, quicklook

Once you open a file with QuickLook, it displays an image.
Is it possible to get the image shown on QLPreviewPanel?
Or maybe open panel and do a screenshot of the Panel's View with the image?

Tried using QLThumbnailImageCreate, but for some reason result is nil. Even though, the "Preview" app generates a correct thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: [How to put the QLPreviewPanel show as a popover in cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959375/how-to-put-the-qlpreviewpanel-show-as-a-popover-in-cocoa/24341301)

I created a view in IB.
Created a class.

```
class MAQuickLookItem: NSObject, QLPreviewItem {

var previewItemURL: URL?
var previewItemTitle: String?

}
```

and then

```
    let view = QLPreviewView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, previewView.frame.size.width, previewView.frame.size.height), style: .normal)
    previewView.addSubview(view!)

    let item = MAQuickLookItem()
    item.previewItemTitle = self.previewFiles?[0].widePath
    item.previewItemURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: (self.previewFiles?[0].widePath)!)

    view?.previewItem = item
```

Now you can simply do a screenshot of the view.